# Python script: get latest tag info from remote Git repository?

Tags: python

I have found a way to get the info on the latest Git tag from the remote repository:

`git ls-remote --tags --refs --sort="version:refname" git://github.com/git/git.git | awk -F/ 'END{print$NF}'`

This works fine from the command line.

How would I get this info from the python script?

I tried [os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), but it doesn't seem like a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and do what your `awk` incantation does in Python (namely print the last line's last `/`-separated segment).

Using the list form of arguments for `subprocess.check_output` ensures you don't need to think about shell escaping (in fact, the shell isn't even involved).

```
import subprocess

repo_url = "https://github.com/git/git.git"
output_lines = subprocess.check_output(
    [
        "git",
        "ls-remote",
        "--tags",
        "--refs",
        "--sort=version:refname",
        repo_url,
    ],
    encoding="utf-8",
).splitlines()
last_line_ref = output_lines[-1].rpartition("/")[-1]
print(last_line_ref)
```